# Status/KPI List View

Tags: list, custom-list

I have a list for users to enter information for their team, and I want to take the sum of a teams data and display it.

What I have right now is a KPI/Status list that sums up the items in a team view I have created, which works, but doesn't display the data as I'd like. I only want to show the Value column, and not the Status or Goal.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option you could use via the Status list is to use the "Show indicator only", if i recall correctly. I've stumbled on the same problem, and moved on to either:

1. PerformancePoint using a SharePoint List as source (requires
   Enterprise license) but its power is way beyond whatever Status
   indicators could ever let you achieve, and than you could display
   those Scorecards to display multiple KPIs wherever in your site
   collection you want.
2. Use the HTML Column trick - which enables you to create a Calculated Column that generates HTML which gets rendered by the JavaScript hosted in page (see here http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/)
3. XSLTView / DataView Web parts - could also get you there, however you would require SharePoint Designer 2010 (free).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I haven't had a chance to try out your suggestions, but would it be possible to create a calculated column, set it equal to the Value, then hide the goal/value/indicator columns?